# How to read a column definition of type ENUM & convert it to array \ list

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums

I have a table in which one of column of type `ENUM('val1', 'val2', 'val3')`

```
create table tab1{
  col1 varchar(20),
  col2 varchar(20),
  col3 ENUM('val1', 'val2', 'val3'),
  col4 varchar(20)
}
```

Now, in Java, I'm using JPA & want to read the column definition to convert the col3 enum values to array \ list. (So that i don't need to hard code emum elements & change in table definition  can reflect in code without any code change).

Is it possible? If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no type called ENUM, an ENUM is a string object with a value chosen from a list of permitted values that are enumerated explicitly in the column specification at table creation time, For tables, just set it to a string and add a constraint that it is within a certain set.

```
CREATE TABLE tab1(
col1 VARCHAR(20),
col2 VARCHAR(20),
col3 VARCHAR(10),
col4 VARCHAR(20),
CONSTRAINT cons_tab1_col3 CHECK (col3 IN ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')));
```

Create an enum called yourEnumName:

```
public enum yourEnumName{
    val1,
    val2,
    val3
}
```

in your entity add an attribut that represent your enum for exemple

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private yourEnumName enumName;
```

Hope that help you.